# How create notification topic for Firebase and use this?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can create notifications for single user and for all users in my app, but I can't understand and find information about notification  with create topic.
For this need create separate service and how do my topics dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a service when you want to subscribe to a topic. Just call anywhere in your app:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

Also see the section [Subscribe the client app to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I tryed do it in my service, but after started my app, in Firebase console my topic hasn't appeared. Maybe problem in my old version support repository?

Comment: It takes some hours before the topic is shown in the Firebase Console. But the subscription is in place and you can send messages to it through the API already.

Comment: i'm using cordova-plugin-firebase : how can i create a topic so i can test it using console notifications ?