# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Create topic message from client

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was unable to find anything in the FCM documentation that answers my question -- the documentation doesn't explicitly say either way.  My question is:

Can I create and send a topic message to FCM from an iOS or Android client?

What I'd like to do is have the client create a topic message, and have FCM send notifications to all subscribers of that topic. I was hoping to accomplish this without creating an actual FCM server.

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't think I was clear in my original question.  I know how to subscribe to a topic, and I'm well aware that when I subscribe to a topic, that topic will be created if it doesn't already exist.

I want to *send a message to a topic from a client*. I'm looking for functionality along the lines as

```
FIRMessaging.messaging().send(toTopic: "/topics/example")
```

I'm asking if such functionality exists.

Comment: Topics are automatically created when your either subscribe to them or send a message to them. It may take a few hours before new topics show up in the Firebase Notifications console, but you can already send messages to them before that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264202/how-create-notification-topic-for-firebase-and-use-this

Comment: I updated my question to be a little clearer.

Comment: There is no way to send messages directly from a device to other devices. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t (for iOS, but it applies to all SDKs).

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thank you for referencing the other answer; I was unable to find it earlier.