# I want to create topic in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to create topic in Firebase console for cloud messaging but I don't know how to create it. I want to send message to all the users who have installed my android app and the only way I found is through topic and I do not how to create it

Comment: As far as i know topics are (auto) created when people subscribe to them... https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions

Comment: Topics are auto-created when you subscribe to them, or when  you send a message to them through the FCM API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264202/how-create-notification-topic-for-firebase-and-use-this/40265168#40265168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FirebaseMessaging first you will need to subscribe to a topic and whenever you send a message with respect to the topic, all the users subscribed to the topic will get the notification.
Please refer to [Send Messages using topic in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

**Lets take a example:**

I am using a famous books app where there are multiple books listing and I liked a book named 'XYZ' and I want to get notified whenever there is anything related to book XYZ. So I will subscribe to topic XYZ and server will broadcast a notification using the topic 'XYZ' and as I have subscribed to topic 'XYZ' I will get the respective message.

Comment: But I am want to create topic on the server, like 'XYZ' I want to create it on the server. How can I do that?

Comment: @Kashi When you will subscribe to topic then topic will be created on server if not created.

Comment: Must say, the current method is counter-intuitive. Imagine a magazine not yet created. A reader can subscribe to it? Then when a publisher thinks about creating a magazine, they look for what people have subscribed to? It gets stranger: you can't find that list of topics as publisher - you have to type in words and see if a hit comes up.